# Publish IIS worker process .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing an ASP.NET Core Web API. When I build the application, there is no issue, but when I publish it to a folder, I always get an issue. I have tried a few ways but it doesn't work.

Publish error:

[image: Publish Error]

Comment: i think error message is clear that your dll is used by another process. i think your iis site is running. stop it before publishing again.

Comment: There are many IIS process is running in the site. Currently the code is one server. When i tried to publish it i am getting this.. I don't know which process need to be stopped that's why concern.

Comment: [Does this github issue useful to u ?](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10088)

Comment: Try to delete `bin`, `obj` and `.vs` folders, and restart your visual studio 2019/2022, if it not works, pls upgrade your visual studio to latest version, then check again.